# How to tell vscode to <C-D> only with case and word matching?

Tags: visual-studio-code

This is driving me crazy. The most powerful command on VsCode became useless since word-matching and case-matching are not enabled by default.

Before using  I have to use   to enable these two options.

Is there a way to make it default? Or enable it each time I use ?

Comment: set these options in the find dialog

Comment: This is even worse, you ask me to use my mouse each time I wanna use my keyboard :(

Comment: No , the find dialog remembers the setting of these 3 buttons

Comment: Are you referring to the Find Widget or Search across files?  Or both?